# Few supported devices on Google Play Console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest, google-play-console

I have created an app which needs camera permission and uses the package AR Foundation (AR Core) with Unity. When uploading the build to Google Play Console it says that only 240 devices are supported, when previous apps I have released has 10 000+. **What can I do to support more devices?**

- The only difference between this app and previous successful apps is that this one requires access to camera and uses the AR Core package.
- I have a minimum required API level of 24 which is stated in the [Google AR documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices).
- I changed every uses-feature in the android manifest file to false:

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ```

  ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="24"
       android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

   <supports-screens
       android:anyDensity="true"
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
       android:xlargeScreens="true" />

   <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
       android:required="false" />

   <uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
       android:required="false" />
   <uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
       android:required="false" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

   <uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar"
       android:required="false" />
   <uses-feature
       android:name="com.google.ar.core.depth"
       android:required="optional" />

   <queries>
       <package android:name="com.google.ar.core" />
   </queries>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <application
       android:extractNativeLibs="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
           android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
           android:launchMode="singleTask"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>

           <meta-data
               android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
               android:value="true" />
       </activity>

       <meta-data
           android:name="unity.splash-mode"
           android:value="0" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="unity.splash-enable"
           android:value="True" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="unity.build-id"
           android:value="23094d1f-7ffd-4f03-8914-045a212a3e8c" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
           android:value="true" />
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.ar.core"
           android:value="required" /> <!-- The minimal version code of ARCore APK required for an app using this SDK. -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version"
           android:value="202940000" /> <!-- This activity is critical for installing ARCore when it is not already present. -->
       <activity
           android:name="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
           android:excludeFromRecents="true"
           android:exported="false"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
           android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity"
           android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity"
           android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.unity3d.services.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
           android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
   </application>
  ```